# Restfull Webservice gets another String

Tags: java, xml, string, web-services

I want to create a XML in a String. When i call it over the webserver it gets the same string the hole time. When called from the server it self, it works fine. I get 2 diffrent strings from the same method.

This is the method to build the xml :
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

```
    builder.append("<regions>");
    for (Region region : world.getRegions()) {
        builder.append("<region><name>" + region.getName() + "</name>");
        double numCult = 0.0;
        double numAtheists = 0.0;
        double population = region.getPopulation();

        if(region.getHumansByReligion(cult) != null) {
            numCult = (double) region.getHumansByReligion(cult).size();
            numCult = (100.0 * (numCult / population));
        }

        if(region.getHumansByReligion(atheism) != null) {
            numAtheists = (double) region.getHumansByReligion(atheism).size();
            numAtheists = 100.0 * (numAtheists / population);
        }
        double numInfidel = 100.0 - (numAtheists + numCult);

        if(numCult > numAtheists) {
            if(numCult > numInfidel) {
                builder.append("<cult>cult</cult><value>" + (int)numCult + "</value>");
            } else {
                builder.append("<cult>infidel</cult><value>" + (int)numInfidel + "</value>");
            }
        } else if(numAtheists > numInfidel) {
            builder.append("<cult>atheism</cult><value>" + (int)numAtheists + "</value>");
        } else {
            builder.append("<cult>infidel</cult><value>" + (int)numInfidel + "</value>");
        }
        builder.append("</region>");
    }
    builder.append("</regions>");
    return builder.toString();
```

I get this:

```
<regions><region><name>North America</name><cult>cult</cult><value>109</value></region><region><name>South America</name><cult>cult</cult><value>105</value></region><region><name>Africa</name><cult>atheism</cult><value>108</value></region><region><name>Europe</name><cult>atheism</cult><value>105</value></region><region><name>Oceania</name><cult>infidel</cult><value>100</value></region><region><name>Asia</name><cult>atheism</cult><value>113</value></region></regions>
```

Webserver method:

```
@Path("/getStats")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getStats() {
        String xml = game.getGameStats();
        System.out.println("XML"+xml);
        return "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + xml ;
    }
```

This is the output by calling from webservice:

```
<regions>
<region>
<name>North America</name>
<cult>infidel</cult>
<value>100</value>
</region>
<region>
<name>South America</name>
<cult>infidel</cult>
<value>99</value>
</region>
<region>
<name>Africa</name>
<cult>infidel</cult>
<value>99</value>
</region>
<region>
<name>Europe</name>
<cult>infidel</cult>
<value>100</value>
</region>
<region>
<name>Oceania</name>
<cult>infidel</cult>
<value>100</value>
</region>
<region>
<name>Asia</name>
<cult>infidel</cult>
<value>100</value>
</region>
</regions>
```

Comment: If you debug it, in the first line of the service method are you getting the String you've post in the question; but in the following line are you getting the response  shown? sure?

Comment: yep and i have no idea why... edit: ah sry i read it wrong, if i call the method from within the same class i get the first one, when called from the webservice i get the second one.

Comment: seems barely impossible... is the variable named ```xml``` hiding a class variable? I mean, the first String has ```<cult>cult</cult>``` but the second one ```<cult>VAR</cult>``` which is so strange because the method appends the final String ```<cult>cult</cult>```

Comment: i edited my comment. the method returns a string. when i call it within the class game i get another xml then when i call the same method from the webservice.

Comment: Ok, then it seems to be a problem with the variables of your method, not the webservice itself. My recommendation is to debug it carefully checking every external variable of the method; IMO the webservice is correct.

Comment: Hmm it seems like he makes a new game everytime i call the webserivce...

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your comment *it seems like he makes a new game everytime i call the webserivce* I answer with a possible scenario.

Let's say we have the `Game` class (which has the game logic) which we are going to inject into our webservice called `WebService` A possible solution could be:

```
@Named
public class Game implements Serializable {

   public String getGameStats() {
      ....
   }

}

@Path("/")
public class WebService {

    // inject the game logic as a dependency
    @Inject
    private Game myGame

    @Path("/getStats")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getStats() {
        String xml = myGame.getGameStats();
        return "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + xml ;
    }
   ....
}
```

Now, if we want to have just one instance of the `Game` to the whole app, add the `@Singleton` annotation.

Tip: Don't forget to add `implements Serializable`

Comment: just curious how does Serializable annotation makes a difference here ?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a static method in an own class to stop it from overwriting...

```
public class GameManager {
    private static Game game = null;
    private static Player player = null;

    public static void startGame() {
        player = new Player(0, "Demo", "Player", "demo.player@test.com", "DemoPlayer", "1234");
        game = new Game(player,"Demo");

        game.start();
    }

    public static String getGameStats() {
        return game.getGameStats();
    }
}
```